# Woher kommt das Wort "Bulle"

Tags: synonym

Woher kommt das Wort "Bulle"? Es wird im Jargon für den "Polizisten" als  *beleidigendes* Synonym verwendet.

Comment: Wikipedia kennt diese [Erklärung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polizeivollzugsbeamter#Der_Ausdruck_.E2.80.9EBulle.E2.80.9C): "Im 18. Jahrhundert wurden die Vorgänger der modernen Polizisten Landpuller oder Bohler genannt."

Comment: Den Gegner in einem (Klassen-)Kampf als Tier zu verunglimpfen ist althergebrachte Praxis. Aber warum Deutsche gerade die Kuh als Beleidigung gewählt haben und z.B. Amerikaner das Schwein, ist im einzelnen vermutlich nicht begründbar.

Comment: Laut dem Wikipediaartikel ist Bulle nicht automatisch als Beleidung zu werten (Vgl. "Der Bulle von Tölz"). Spannend!

Comment: Ich mag mich jetzt irren, aber ich bin mir ziemlich sicher, dass der Bruder meiner Ex (selbst Bulle) mal meinte, dass "Bulle" als Beamtenbeleidigung geahndet werden kann und demnach dann doch automatisch als Beleidigung gelten würde. Aber wie gesagt. Ist ein paar Jahre her und ich mag was verwechseln.

Comment: @DavidSeek, es kommt auf die Umstände an (siehe https://www.anwalt.de/rechtstipps/darf-man-polizisten-als-bullen-bezeichnen_001552.html). Die Beamtenbeleidigung ist in Deutschland kein besonderer Straftatbestand, Zivilpersonen gehen gegen Beleidung aber nur eben selten vor.

Comment: @Iris Danke für den Link und die Aufklärung

Comment: Vgl. En. *bully* "Fiesling", oder Lat. *bulla*, *die Bulle von ..." (Dekret).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Der [Artikel zu *Bulle* im Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Bulle_Stier_Polizeibeamter) hilft in diesem Falle nicht weiter, da er lediglich eine Bedeutungsübersicht gibt, aber keine etymologischen Zusammenhänge erklärt.

Stattdessen enthält das [deutsche Wiktionary einen Artikel](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Bulle#Substantiv.2C_m) darüber. Dort werden folgende Möglichkeiten für die Herkunft angegeben (übrigens ohne Verweis auf *Bulle* im Sinne des Tieres):

- Von der umgangssprachlichen Abkürzung `Pole` (für Polizist; heute noch verwendet u.a. in *Polente*); im Laufe der Jahre ist durch das Zusammenfallen der Vokale *o* und *u* und durch Abschwächen des Konsonanten dann das heutige *Bulle* geworden (beschleunigt durch die Assoziation mit dem Tier)
- Von den veralteten niederländischen Worten `Landpuller` oder `Bohler` für Landjäger (also den Vorgängern der Polizisten); beide Worte gehen auf das niederländische `bol` (deutsch: *kluger Mensch*) zurück

### Quellen

- Kluge, Friedrich; bearbeitet von Seebold, Elmar: Etymologisches Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache, Berlin/New York 2001. S. 160
- Krämer, Walter; Sauer, Wolfgang: Lexikon der populären Sprachirrtümer. Mißverständnisse, Denkfehler und Vorurteile von Altbier bis Zyniker, München 2006

Comment: Verwandt mit "buhlen", "Nebenbuhler", hinsichtlich "Jäger"?

Answer (score 0):

Ich denke im Duden findet du die Zusammenhänge: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Bulle_Stier_Polizeibeamter#b2-Bedeutung-3

1. a) geschlechtsreifes männliches Rind
   b) männliches Tier verschiedener Großwildarten
2. (salopp, meist abwertend) Mann von auffallend kräftigem, plumpem Körperbau
3. (umgangssprachlich, oft abwertend) Polizei-, Kriminalbeamter
4. (salopp, Soldatensprache) jemand, der einen einflussreichen, einträglichen Posten hat

Aus Bedeutung 1 leitet sich Bedeutung 2 ab. Aus 2 dann 3. Vielleicht liegt auch noch 4 dazwischen.

Beachte auch den Hinweis unter 'Beispiele 3'. Es gab/gibt(?) wohl auch eine nicht abwertende Nutzung. Ich würde es aber nicht darauf ankommen lassen. Und wie bei vielen Worten hat es vermutlich im Laufe der Jahre auch hier eine Bedeutungs/Werte-Verschiebung gegeben.

Comment: Möglich. Die meisten Quellen haben aber eine andere Erklärung.